# Visual Studio Code & node.js: Debugger exits without error message

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Node v4.2.6, VS Code 0.10.6, Windows 8.1

VS Code exits without any error message when calling "console.log" with a complex object.

Calling the same code without the console line works fine.

When stepping over the code-line, the object gets printed to the output window but the the debugger exits.

VS code does not display any error message, neither in the "Variables" nor the "Output" pane.

Any help is appreciated,

thx

Gera.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be node.js error [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2484).

There is also a fix [link](https://github.com/TheAlphaNerd/node/commit/27fe67b95de917c80282212194127bacf4095cf4) you need to get this patch and rebuild node.js.

What version of node.js do you use? Seems to work well with 5.5.

Comment: hi, i'm using v4.2.6 node version.